# Go - libVLC module on Windows

Tags: windows, go, vlc, libvlc

I'm having a problem with running the libVLC module

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    vlc "github.com/adrg/libvlc-go/v3"
)

func main() {
    // Initialize libVLC. Additional command line arguments can be passed in
    // to libVLC by specifying them in the Init function.
    if err := vlc.Init("--no-video", "--quiet"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer vlc.Release()

    // Create a new player.
    player, err := vlc.NewPlayer()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        player.Stop()
        player.Release()
    }()
```

I'm running Windows with Go and MinGW installed, and I'm getting

```
.\main.go:29:19: undefined: vlc.Init
.\main.go:33:15: undefined: vlc.Release
.\main.go:36:21: undefined: vlc.NewPlayer
```

Anyone knows what the issue might be?

**UPDATE:**

I've reinstalled Go, [GCC](https://github.com/go101/go101/wiki/CGO-Environment-Setup) and added both to PATH, enabled [CGO](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/cgo-tutorial/#Why_you_shouldn%E2%80%99t_use_CGO) and now the compiler says this:

```
# runtime/cgo
cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
```

**UPDATE #2:**

Figured it's a fault of the gcc compiler not linking. Installed TDM-GCC using instructions [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2rv-CobZpA).

Now the output is the following:

```
# github.com/adrg/libvlc-go/v3
C:\Users\user\go\pkg\mod\github.com\adrg\libvlc-go\v3@v3.1.5\av.go:4:11: fatal error: vlc/vlc.h: No such file or directory
    4 | // #include <vlc/vlc.h>
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

My guess is that the VLC SDK is not installed properly.
I've tried the process described [here](https://github.com/adrg/libvlc-go/wiki/Install-on-Windows), but still no luck.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my machine. Are you trying to run this on the playground?

Comment: That's strange. I'm running this on my main WIndows 10 machine using Powershell in VSCode.

Comment: Seems unlikely to be the culprit but just to be safe, have you run `go mod tidy`?

Comment: I have right now. Didn't solve the issue though.

Comment: That package is a wrapper around `libVLC`. Do you have `libVLC` its dependencies and gcc all installed? Did you set `CC`  to point to your compiler? Did you disable cgo in your environment?

Comment: Hi @JimB, I've followed a guide here: https://github.com/adrg/libvlc-go/wiki/Install-on-Windows#install-libvlc-sdk before, but it still shows undefined.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre], these are undefined because you are not building with cgo for some reason.

Comment: Hello @BrokenArmor, I've followed the instructions there and set the variables. But still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

So I've run it using the cmd instead of Powershell and the issue seems to be resolved. If anyone knows why is that, I'd be glad to know. I've tried restarting both – the IDE with terminals and Windows itself.

## Update #3

The program was built successfully, but now it says that the "libvlc.dll" is missing.

## Update #4

Added the dll from zip file of the SDK

```
2023/06/30 21:18:08 could not initialize module
exit status 1
```

Comment: I've had the same error "could not initialize module" on OSX, in my case I solved it by adding the VLC_PLUGIN_PATH variable to the shell environment`export VLC_PLUGIN_PATH="/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS"`